# Ampissimo o amplissimo?

Tags: orthography

A volte l'incertezza sull'annosa questione ritorna, e allora, visto che si può fare, per una volta propongo la domanda e offro la mia risposta.

Qual è la forma più corretta, "**ampissimo**" o "**amplissimo**"?

Answer (score 4):

Si possono usare entrambe le forme, sono entrambe corrette: "*ampissimo*" è il superlativo regolare dell'italiano "*ampio*" mentre "*amplissimo*" conserva la reminiscenza latina da "*amplus-a-um*", "*amplissimus-a-um*". "*Amplissimo*" è una forma letteraria e maggiormente diffusa.

A favore dell'uso di entrambe le forme vi sono la [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/ampissimo-o-amplissimo_(La_grammatica_italiana)/), L'Accademia della Crusca (Lessicografia, dalla [1º edizione del 1612](http://www.lessicografia.it/AMPISSIMO_ed1) alla 5º edizione del 1863-1923) e persino il [dizionario del Corriere della Sera](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-si-dice/A/ampissimo-amplissimo.shtml). Anche [Luca Serianni](http://www1.adnkronos.com/Archivio/AdnAgenzia/1998/01/16/Cultura/ACCADEMIA-CRUSCA-UN-GLOSSARIO-PER-EVITARE-GLI-STRAFALCIONI_124200.php), nella Garzantina, è della medesima opinione.

Insomma, non vi è chi sia contrario all'uso di "*ampissimo*". Perché?

Semplice: storicamente, "*ampissimo*" è sempre stato presente in lingua italiana, fin dagli inizi.

È usato più volte da Boccaccio ([1343](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/b/boccaccio/elegia_di_madonna_fiammetta/pdf/boccaccio_elegia_di_madonna_fiammetta.pdf), [1351](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/b/boccaccio/decameron_branca/pdf/boccaccio_decameron_branca.pdf), [1361](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/b/boccaccio/trattatello_in_laude_di_dante/pdf/tratta_p.pdf), [1368](http://www.classicitaliani.it/boccaccio/prosa/Genealogia%202.htm), [1375](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/b/boccaccio/il_comento_alla_divina_commedia_etc/pdf/il_com_p.pdf), etc.), [Bembo (1505)](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/b/bembo/gli_asolani/pdf/gli_as_p.pdf), [Nicolo Tartalea Brisciano (1565)](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/e/euclides/euclide_megarense_etc/pdf/euclid_p.pdf), [Tasso (1570)](http://www.classicitaliani.it/tasso/discorsi/discorsi_poema_eroico_03_1824.htm), [Intorcetta (1672)](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/i/intorcetta/compendiosa_narratione/pdf/intorcetta_compendiosa_narratione.pdf), [Muratori (1745)](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/m/muratori_lodovico/della_forza_della_fantasia/pdf/muratori_della_forza.pdf), [Parini (1763)](http://www.classicitaliani.it/parini/parini16_2_poesie_varie.htm), [Casti (1802)](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/c/casti/gli_animali_parlanti/pdf/gli_an_p.pdf), [Villabianca (1802)](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/v/villabianca/autoapologia/pdf/autoap_p.pdf), [Alfieri (1803)](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/a/alfieri/vita/pdf/vita_p.pdf), [Alessandro Volta (1816)](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/v/volta/collezione_dell_opere_3/pdf/volta_collezione_dell_opere_3.pdf), [Guerrazzi (1853)](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/g/guerrazzi/beatrice_cenci_storia_del_secolo_xvi/pdf/beatri_p.pdf), [De Amicis (1872)](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/d/de_amicis/spagna/pdf/de_amicis_spagna.pdf), [Gozzano (1907)](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/g/gozzano/tutte_le_poesie/pdf/gozzano_tutte_le_poesie.pdf) e consultando [google books](https://www.google.it/search?q=%22ampissimo%22&btnG=Cerca+nei+libri&tbm=bks&tbo=1&hl=it&gws_rd=ssl) se ne potrebbero raccogliere molte altre occorrenze, più o meno illustri (io mi sono limitato ai siti www.liberliber.it e www.classicitaliani.it).

Per accertarsi dell'uso corrente basta googlare un po', se ne trovano molte occorrenze un po' in tutti i contesti.

Da notare come [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ampissimo%2C+amplissimo&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1200&year_end=2014&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Campissimo%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bampissimo%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAmpissimo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Camplissimo%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bamplissimo%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAmplissimo%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAMPLISSIMO%3B%2Cc0) non sia molto d'aiuto in quanto sembra quasi totalmente ignorare "ampissimo" che invece, come si è visto, era alquanto comune sin dal Trecento. Conferma tuttavia quanto rilevato dalle maggiori fonti citate su, che "amplissimo" sia più frequente di "ampissimo".